# how do you stop inspect element in ie 11 switching to visual studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, internet-explorer-11, element, inspect

How do you stop inspect element in internet explorer 11 switching to visual studio 2013 when my application is running? When you click on inspect element in ie 11 it automatically switches window to VS 2013.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way to disable just the element inspection.
But disabling the Browser Link feature should do the trick.

It can be disabled either through the Visual Studio IDE

[image: Browser Link control in Visual Studio]

or by adding the 'vs:EnableBrowserLink' app setting in the web.config

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false"></add>
    .
    .
    .
  </appSettings>
```